# Initialize all jquery files and inline js after load content through ajax

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Hi I have use Advanced AJAX Page Loader plugin for load content part through ajax. but after load content through ajax some other js not working. Like i have use own crosell and pretty photos js. how can i reinitialize all js files after ajax.

Anyone can have solution. Please help me thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you ask this question on plugin support forum ?

Comment: use event delegation

Comment: Check in that plugin settings, and add the required callbacks. 
See this:
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584167/prettyphoto-and-ajax-loaded-content)

Comment: initialize the pulgins in the success function of the ajax pager

Comment: Thanks to all, if i have lots of files then i need to initialize all files after success ajax? is it any solution after ajax load all js files load using one function?

Comment: You, have to, no other option.

Comment: Ok, I use jQuery(document).trigger("ready"); after ajax complete but it's not working for me.